# How to use android ndk r9b to compile FFMPEG for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to design an Android app which can play and edit video by FFMPEG commands.
But I don't know how to use FFMPEG on Android. I have tried many methods searched from Google, but they are too old to implement.
Now, the newest version of FFMPEG is 2.1.1 and the Android-NDK's version is r9b. My operating system is Linux mint 15.
How can I use eclipse IDE on my OS to implement an Android app which has FFMPEG's newest decoder and encoder?

Comment: I was able to successfully compile FFMPEG for Android under Ubuntu following the code from here: https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/source/checkout

Comment: Just follow the instructions of following link: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/ I did the same for NDK r9b recently with the help of above link.

Comment: Roman has a special update for r9: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

Comment: 1.First install the libraries mentioned in the below link
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide 2.Once all the dependency libraries are installed then follow the below link
http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/ Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: You can download http://github.com/yixia/FFmpeg-Vitamio, run build_android.sh

Answer (score 0):

[IJKplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer) compiles ffmpeg for android using ndk as part of its make process. The configuration files can be slightly modified to enable generation of ffmpeg binary for android.

Specifically comment out lines in config/module-lite.sh before running the compile-ffmpeg script:

```
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-programs"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-ffmpeg"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-avfilter"
```

And it will generate the ffmpeg executable.

The [IJKplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer) project will also give you a hint on how to use ffmpeg in android programs.